# Expose metafields to the Storefront API error

Tags: shopify, storefront

I want to expose the product metafields in shopify to my Storefront API.
I am referring to following documentation. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/metafields/storefront-api-metafields

Following is the content of my body

```
mutation($input: MetafieldStorefrontVisibilityInput!) {     
  metafieldStorefrontVisibilityCreate( input: $input ) {         
    metafieldStorefrontVisibility {             
      id         
    }         
    userErrors {             
      field message         
    }     
  }
}
```

Following are the GRAPHQL VARIABLES

```
{
  "input": {
    "namespace": "global",
    "key": "description_tag",
    "ownerType": "PRODUCT"
  }
}
```

Following is the URL

```
https://posdev07.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/graphql.json
```

I get following error when I make the request.

```
{"errors":{"query":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}
```